# Python write Russian, Mandarin Characters into an ArcGIS Map Document

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2012

I'm using python for visual studio 2012 (python version 2.7.2) , I have a dictionary with Russian ('УТВЕРЖДЕНО') and mandarin symbols ('项目名称'), when I write these to the ArcGIS Map document using python, all I see in the document are these "????", I have used this coding:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso8859_5 -*-
```

Still those question marks show up, is there a way to handle this?

Comment: don't you have to use utf-8 instead?

Comment: I used that too, still the question marks show up

Comment: Can I use Codecs to encode the characters?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module, and be sure that the things you're trying to write to file are `unicode`. (See Kumar McMillan's [talk from PyCon 2008](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) for much more detail).

Here's a minimal example of how you might write Russian and Mandarin Chinese characters to a file using the `codecs` module.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    ## by Kumar McMillan ( http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ )
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
    return obj

mystring = 'String input: УТВЕРЖДЕНО, 项目名称\n'

mystring_unicode = u'Unicode input: УТВЕРЖДЕНО, 项目名称\n'

with codecs.open("filename.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
    stream.write(to_unicode_or_bust(mystring))
    stream.write(to_unicode_or_bust(mystring_unicode))
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's a more permanent link to the slides for more context: https://github.com/kumar303/unicode-in-python